# Python: How to run some specific code snippet for 10 minutes from current time?

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, pyautogui

**CODE**

```
from random import *
import pyautogui, datetime, sys, time 

ts = time.strftime('%X') #saving current time in ts
scroll_up = pyautogui.scroll(50) #scroll up 50 "clicks"
```

I want this code to run 10 minutes from current time.

Suppose current time in `ts is -> 13:02:08` and I want to run that code till `13:12:08` and after 10 minutes the code stops.

How can I do that?

I'm trying to find the difference between human and computer behavior (pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a while loop and check the time delta (change)

```
from datetime import datetime

start_time = datetime.now()

while True:

    #  To something

    current_time = datetime.now()
    duration = current_time - start_time
    duration_minutes = ((duration.seconds % 3600) / 60) 

    if duration_minutes > 10:
        break # exit loop
```

Comment: Thank you Thank you so much, it worked to me. I've tried of that current_time - start_time but i didn't get how to give that if(duration_minutes > 10). I thought now how noob i'm. Anyway Thanks